# For Loop Ends Batch File Execution

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

My batch file is silently ending execution on the first loop (`for /d "delims= eol=|" %%d in (*.*) do (`) and I can't tell why.

- I'm not calling any other batch files
- My subfolder names DO contain spaces, which I tried to handle with `"delims= eol=|"`

I never see `!parent!!folder!` echoed and it doesn't pause at the end. What am I doing wrong?

---

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

pushd "%~dp0"

set "parent=%~dp0"
echo !parent!
set "destination=\\(test destination folder)\"

rem SET "destination=\\(prod destination folder)\"


set "FileCount=0"


for /d "delims= eol=|" %%d in (*.*) do (
    set "folder=%%d"
    echo !parent!!folder!
    pause
    for %%f in ("!parent!!folder!\(file identifying-pattern)*.DAT") do (
        echo "File Type 1"
        pause
        if !FileCount! lss 200 ( 
            set /a !FileCount!+=1
            ECHO !FileCount!
            ECHO !parent!!folder!%%f
            ECHO !destination!%%f
            MOVE "%%f" "!destination!"
        )
    (
    for %%f in ("!parent!!folder!\(file identifying-pattern)*.DAT") do (
        echo "File Type 2"
        pause
        if !FileCount! lss 200 ( 
            set /a !FileCount!+=1
            ECHO !FileCount!
            ECHO !parent!!folder!%%f
            ECHO !destination!%%f
            MOVE "%%f" "!destination!"
        )
    )
)


for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
set "folder=%%d"
if not %%d==Archive (
if not %%d==Hold (

dir /b "!folder!"|find /v "">nul && ECHO "!folder! NOT EMPTY"||rmdir "!parent!!folder!"

)
)
)


pause

popd
```

Comment: Why not `For /F` instead of `For /D`?

Comment: `for /d` can handle the spaces, no need for `delims` or `eol` (in fact, they aren't allowed with `/d`). Also, no need for `*.*`, `for` can handle a simple `*` for *all* matches. Might there be an extension or not.

Comment: ... and you don't see your `echo` output, because your script stops with a syntax error at the `for /d` line. For Troubleshooting don't run your script with a doubleclick, but manual from an open command line window. And run it with `echo on` to see, what exactly happens.

Comment: @Stephan Unfortunately getting rid of the delims and eol parameters and commenting the echo off line and running from the command line doesn't display any errors, nor does it complete successfully.

Comment: @Compo Mostly because I was getting the subfolder name and saving it to !folder! there. Do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: `For /D` doesn't have a `delims` etc. option, and if you were only after directories, why use `*.*` unless you only wanted directories with a **`.`** in it's name.

Comment: @Compo Both are good points. I inherited these line from someone else: `for /d %%d in (*.*) do (`,`set "folder=%%d"`. I adapted other parts of the code and when that was no longer working as expected I searched Stack Overflow and saw a suggestion to use delims if you have spaces in the folder names. I do not know why the original writer used `*.*`. You're definitely right, my changes weren't based on firm understanding of batch.

Comment: @Compo I also tried `!parent!\*` before posting this question but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've took a guess at what you were doing, *trying not to change the structure too much*!

You'll need to add your destinations on lines `4` and `5` and your file patterns to lines `8` and `9` as necessary. *(Please make sure you do not end your destination paths with back slashes)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%~dp0" 2>Nul || Exit /B

Set "Destination=\\(test destination folder)"
Rem Set "Destination=\\(prod destination folder)"
If Not Exist "%destination%\" Exit /B

Set "Pattern1=(file identifying-pattern)"
Set "Pattern2=(file identifying-pattern)"

Set /A Type1Count=Type2Count=0
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%A In (*) Do (
    For %%B In ("%%A\%Pattern1%*.dat") Do (
        Echo "File Type 1"
        Set /A Type1Count +=1
        If !Type1Count! Lss 200 (
            Echo !Type1Count!. "%CD%\%%A\%%B" --^> "%Destination%\%%B"
            If Not Exist "%Destination%\%%B\" MD "%Destination%\%%B"
            Move /Y "%%B" "%Destination%\%%B">Nul
        )
    )
    For %%C In ("%%A\%Pattern2%*.dat") Do (
        Echo "File Type 2"
        Set /A Type2Count +=1
        If !Type2Count! Lss 200 (
            Echo !Type2Count!. "%CD%\%%B\%%C" --^> "%Destination%\%%C"
            If Not Exist "%Destination%\%%C\" MD "%Destination%\%%C"
            Move /Y "%%C" "%Destination%\%%C">Nul
        )
    )
    If /I Not "%%A"=="Archive" (
        If /I Not "%%A"=="Hold" (
            Set "file="
            For %%D In (*) Do Set "file=1"
            If Defined file (Echo %%A NOT EMPTY) Else RD "%%A" 2>Nul
        )
    )
)

Pause
```

If you're happy with it in your test you can `Rem`ark line `4` and un`Rem`ark line `5`.

Comment: You did a great job of reading my mind - I didn't realize how unclear I was until I was adapting your answer.